# TeXnicCenter and Jabref - refreshing database?

Tags: bibliographies, texniccenter, jabref

After adding a new reference with JabRef, I need to close and restart TeXnicCenter before the entries in the literature database menu of TeXnicCenter get updated. Isn't there a button for refreshing the literature database, so I will see my changes right away?

I also asked on [latex-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=22644&p=76595#p76595)

Comment: Have you asked this on the mailing list of TeXnicCenter? Could be a feature request. BTW: I do not know such an button in TeXnicCenter v2.0 Beta 1 ...

Comment: ok, I have posted also there

Comment: I must second Kurt. And: because it is a feature request, though you did not know, it must be closed here.

Comment: As others have noted, this is essentially a feature request. Nothing wrong with those, but they don't make good questions _here_, so I've closed. Do post back if this gets fixed in TeXnicCenter!

Comment: @user25646: Could you add the link to your feature request on the TeXnicCenter site, please?

Comment: @Bloops There is none: https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/.

Comment: @Bloops I asked on latex community (see the link above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) is only a BiBTeX database manager. On my machine, with an open project, clicking the "Save All" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) in TeXnicCenter does a refresh of the project structure, including that of a Literature database update if the project has been processed under BiBTeX. In TeXstudio to refresh the drop-down list of references after updating your .bib, simply save the .tex you're working in (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).

Comment: @user25646 Also you need to save the `.bib` file in JabRef and recompile in TeXnicCenter then the enrty will be available.

Comment: @percuße: Saving of the `.bib` is a given, since it's done outside of TeXnicCenter. That's what I meant by "processed under BiBTeX: Either via TeXnicCenter itself (as part of the build process) or post-processing it manually.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it took me a while to remember to save the document after compiling a few times. So it wasn't a comment on your answer's integrity :P but just to keep the warnings close to each other. I still can't make it work with BibLaTeX in a project though.